# pgfplotstable: color from cellentry ##1

Tags: pgfplotstable, colortbl, cellcolor

If I have a column with entries like `0,0,red,0,green,0,0,0,brown,0,0,0,...`, 
why does this *not* work:

```
postproc cell content/.code={
\ifnum##1=0 \else
  @cell content={cellcolor{##1}{##1}}       \fi},
```

What do I have to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\pgfplotstableread[]{
No  Color
0    0
1    brown
2    0
3    0
4    red 
5    0
6    green
7    green
8    0
}\mytable

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
columns/Color/.style={
%% Does not work!
%postproc cell content/.code={
%\ifnum##1=0 \else
%  @cell content={cellcolor{##1}{##1}}       \fi},
},
]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you do an `\ifnum` comparison with text. The error says `!Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>   b` where the `b` is the one in `brown`. Haven't tried figuring out an alternative approach.

Comment: Try this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315318/586